# Add validation for dynamically generated fields in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I'm creating a custom WordPress checkout page, which changes based on products in the cart and I need to add validation for form fields, which are dynamically created by `foreach()` loop

Not sure how to create validation for dynamically generated fields and how to save these fields.

This is my code.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    /**
    /* Some previous logic, which returns $items array with this. I will generate it here manually to showcase the structure of $items array. rand() is there just to make these keys unique every time the script is run.
    */

    $i = rand(1,100);
    $j = $i + 1;
    $items = array(
        "querstion".$i."" => array(
            "option 1-1",
            "option 1-2",
            "option 1-3"
        ),
        "querstion".$j.""=> array(
            "option 2-1",
            "option 2-2",
            "option 2-3",
            "option 2-4"
        ),          
    );

    foreach( $items as $key => $val ) {           
        woocommerce_form_field('box_field-' . $key, array(
            'type' => 'radio',
            'options' => $val,
            'class' => array(
                'form-row-wide',
                'custom-radio'
                ),
            'label' => __( $key ) ,
            'required' => true,

            ),
        $checkout->get_value( 'box_field-'.$key ));

        /**
        /* Here is the validation, which doesn't work
        */

        add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', function() use ($key) { 
            if ( isset( $_POST['box_field-' . $key] ) ) {
                $domain = 'woocommerce';
                $box_field = $_POST['box_field-' . $key];
    
                // Empty
                if ( empty ( $box_field ) ) {
                    wc_add_notice( __( 'My error message', $domain ), 'error' );
                }    
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Added `$items` array example.